# images not showing MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

It is my first time uploading from my localhost to a site there is build on a MVC framework. I really do not understand why my images not are showing.
On my localhost the path is: `<img src="~/img/logo-white-small.png">` and it is 100% the same path on the server.

I read around on stackoverflow and saw other questions regarding this. I tried the following possibilities, but they are still not showing. Does anybody have a clue why that is, and how I can solve it?

I tried with:

```
 <img src="~/img/logo-white-small.png">

 <img src='<%=Url.Content("~/img/logo-white-small.png") %>'

 <img src="Url.Content("~/img/logo-white-small.png")">
```

Comment: Is your `logo-white-small.png` definitely included in the project? Could you check that the image is output in the folder when you "Publish" the project?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The image is 100% on the server and on the same path.

Comment: What happens if you try to visit the Url directly to your image? (http://yourdomain.com/img/logo-white-small.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying? Is that *your* site? The logo on the site is an svg file, and has a fall-back (`data-svg-fallback`) of the png (which that, and your link gives me a 404 error, btw)

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what I'm asking **1)** Are you publishing the project and uploading it to your server? **2)** Is the image definitely included in the project? **3)** What happens when you try and visit the image directly in your browser on your website?

Comment: Okay I just find out when I can do. Maybe it is a hack. hardcode in url/img/logo.png. I am just gonna do that. Thank you for the hints :)

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.